# Is the quadratic formula called Bhaskara Formula in any other country beyond Brazil?

Tags: quadratics, math-history

In Brazil, the *quadratic formula*
$$\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4 ac}}{2a}$$
is almost always called *Bhaskara formula*.

I'm probably missing something, but I've never seen, in the literature from other countries,
any use of this terminology *Bhaskara formula* in this context, or even a more direct association of the great mathematician Bhaskara (c. 1114–1185) with this formula.

Have you ever seen this terminology within the math literature you've been exposed? or know about some connection of Bhaskara with the *quadratic formula*?

Comment: If that’s what you want to hear, I can confirm that “Bhaskara formula” is a rare term in the UK.

Comment: Because Bhaskara found the formula independently (I have no comments about who found it first). In fact, he did not find the formula as you write. He was clever enough to not divide by 2 or take square roots, so he left it in the form $ (2ax+b)^2 = b^2 - 4ac $.

Comment: What can you say about the earliest textbook you can find that mentions Bhaskara? I'm thinking of something influential... About grammar and spelling in the U. S., major differences from British English  were encouraged and encoded by one man, Noah Webster (1758-1843). I'm wondering if Brazil has a similar influential figure as regards mathematics education; or, perhaps, some influential textbooks from Portugal...

Comment: Never heard of the term.

Comment: @CraniumClamp, a method for solving the quadratic was well known by indian mathematicians well before Bhaskara (and even credited by Bhaskara). There is no dispute about that. But his books were very influential and popular, helping to disseminate these ideas, what, I believe, ended up associating his name to the quadratic.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I found some material on this question and decided to organize it an answer due to its lenght.

Comment: The fact that the formula's name is not appropriate was discussed many years ago in a short note in [number 39 of *Math Teacher Magazine* (publication of *Brazilian Mathematical Society*)](https://www.rpm.org.br/cdrpm/39/12.htm). However, it seems that it has been little influential and the use is still massive..

Answer (score 7):

@Will Jagy, thanks for the hint. Yesterday I ended up finding a Brazilian M.Sc. Dissertation in Portuguese:

> Guedes, E. 2019. Equação Quadrática e a Contribuição de Bhaskara.
> Universidade Federal do Paraná.

It examines the connection of Bhaskara with the quadratic in a general historical context and in Brazilian math literature.

Guedes suggests that the earliest known association of Bhaskara with the quadratic in Brazilian texts was in 1909, by an influential math pre-college algebra text book:

> Peres y Marin, A. 1909.  Elementos de álgebra. São Paulo: Escolas
> Profissionaes Salesianas.

Peres y Marin, the author of this book was born in Spain in 1858 and moved to Brazil in 1893, spending the rest of his life in Brazil. He is recognized as being a respected math teacher and prolific author.

On the resolution of the quadratic, Peres y Marin shows the quadratic formula, deduced from completing squares, and connects the formula with a footnote saying (in free translation from Portuguese):

> This method of resolution, notable by its simplicity, is due to
> Bhaskara, Indian mathematician from the XII century.

An image of the page in a later edition of the book from 1916 is shown below: [image]