# Why is Apollonius's Theorem called Pappus's Theorem in Japan and South Korea?

Tags: geometry, definition, math-history

Apollonius's theorem a theorem stating the relationship of the median of a triangle and its sides. However when I moved to Japan I noticed the theorem had a different name. Material both online and offline referred to it as  "パップスの定理" or "パップスの中線定理". They mean "Pappus's Theorem" and "Pappus's Median Theorem". Additionally, an exchange student from South Korea told me that she was taught the theorem as "파푸스의 중선정리" which also translates to "Pappus's Median Theorem".

The Pappus's Theorem I am familiar with is a completely different one, and Britannica agrees with me.
https://www.britannica.com/science/Pappuss-theorem

How come the same name refers to two distinct theorems?

Comment: there was a similar question about Brazil,  some other result.  It turned out the was a single important person in mathematical education, year about 1850; this person wrote a textbook that set terms from then on. The thing you can do is search textbooks back, see the earliest uses of your terms. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4543275/is-the-quadratic-formula-called-bhaskara-formula-in-any-other-country-beyond-bra

Comment: "Peres y Marin, the author of this book was born in Spain in 1858 and moved to Brazil in 1893, spending the rest of his life in Brazil. He is recognized as being a respected math teacher and prolific author."

Comment: From [brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/apollonius-theorem/): "*Apollonius's theorem is an elementary geometry theorem relating the length of a median of a triangle to the lengths of its sides. While most of the world refers to it as it is, in East Asia, the theorem is usually referred to as Pappus's theorem or midpoint theorem.*". AFAICT by the automated translation the Japanese wikipedia has it as the [midline theorem](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E7%B7%9A%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86): "*although it is known as Pappus' theorem, it is actually a theorem discovered by Apollonius*".